# Transfer learning with Keras for medical image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transfer-learning

I'm trying to do Transfer Learning from pre-trained model on imagenet to solve a classification task with Lung CT slices.

These slices are stored in `dicom` file, so their value are expressed on 12 bit in Hounsfield scale. My questions are: `preprocess_input` of keras / tf2 api need of a matrix of values in [0,255], so how can I preprocess my images to fed them to a pre-trained convnet? Can I to normalize range of image in [0,1] or it's mandatory to use `preprocess_input` of models? If `preprocess_input` is mandatory, how can I map the 12 bit value in range [0,255]?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pydicom library to convert your image from Dicom format to other formats (i.e. PNG). Then you can feed those converted images normally.

**Installation:**

```
pip install pydicom
```

**Uses:**

```
import pydicom
import cv2
ds = pydicom.read_file(path) # read dicom image
img = ds.pixel_array
cv2.imwrite(save_path, img)
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary to transform pixels value in Hounsfield scale with "rescale slope" and "rescale intercept" attributes before saving ?

Comment: It completely depends on your dataset. Most of the cases you don't need to do that. But if your saved image pixels changes a bit, you can use some utils which is also included in pydicom. Take a look here: https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/generated/pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util.html

Comment: I'm actually using this preprocess step, I think that the code below is equivalent to your solution:

im = float(dcm.RescaleSlope) * dcm.pixel_array.astype('float32') + float(dcm.RescaleIntercept)
    im = np.clip(im, -1024, 3071) # clippa con minimo a 1024 e max a 3071
    im = (im + 1024.) / (3071 + 1024.) # 0-1

    int_slice =  (255*im).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8) # CONVERSION 8 BIT FOR PREPROCESS_INPUT KERAS



What do you think about this code? Is it Correct?

Comment: It looks fine. I will try implementing if I get some more time later.